# Installing PHP 5.4 with pdo_mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mac-osx

I'm try to install PHP 5.4 and I want to use PDO with the MySQL driver.

However, it seems the php54 package does not configure with the --with-pdo-mysql flag.  How can I install this?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm first off all use `./configure --help` to see what options are supported for compiling php5.4.

You could paste here your configure options. I'm guesing that you didnt use option -enable-pdo thats why `--with-pdo-mysql` doesn't work. But it's only a guessing. Paste your configure options.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, pdo was enabled yet no drivers were installed
after a lot of mucking about i discovered that its quite easy to sort, once you know how!
if your php is installed as an apache module, this worked for me (on a mac)

sudo port install php54-mysql

which i guess in linux could be sudo apt-get install php54-mysql?